# VCRUNTIME140_1D error in debug mode with visual studio

Tags: openvino

Hello when im runing visual studio 2017 on debug mode I got this error VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll was not found, I tried to install again visual studio 17 and redistributed c++ 17 but nothing. I check system32 and i cant find this file also there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for ur answer
I found the solution, the problem is that thi sdll vcruntime140_1d.dll is a special dll for VS19. u can find it in MVSC in install directory for your VS19. and is VS17 doesnt have the same version. sso install VS19 INSTEAD OF 17.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the cvruntime140_1D.dll file from your computer. You have to reinstall redistributable c++ and you can find the dll in the system folder.